# How can I access a DLL stored on a client's machine through a web site? Is this possible?

Tags: c#, .net, com, client-side

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to access a **.NET dll** which is stored on a **client machine** trough a **webinterface** (be it html, javascript, silverlight, plugin, ...).
I know this must be possible because I have seen examples of it. For example, if you have a Garmin navigation device, the website asks you to install a firefox plugin and then it can communicate with your device through usb. I need to do something similar (communicate with a dll stored on the machine).

How do I best get started on this? I tried googling around, but can't seem to find the correct terms. *Javascript+com* is something that pops up a lot, but that's *IE-only* right? Can someone point me in the right direction?
Is this even possible, or am I going to run into a lot of security issues?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**
This is just an inquiry to scout my possibilities. Doing what i need from a client app is pretty easy, just messing with installers and versions etc is "tricky". Maintaining and updating a webapp might be a bit easier (all users are always using the same version etc..)

Comment: do you mean [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)?

Comment: You only attempt this if there is no other way. Do you really need to do this?o this?

Comment: Imagine if an *arbitrary* website could run *arbitrary* code on your machine. So now you know why there's no general solution for this. I'd imagine the Garmin plugin you've mentioned is specific to Garmin devices and to Firefox, and as you said, you also had to install it.

Comment: I dunno really, I'm scouting my options, hence the question :-) The thing is, I wrote a client app already which can do what I want, but I want to find out if I can centralize a lot of it. Basically yes, just the part that interacts with the user via these DDL's is the tricky part.

Comment: @Damien yes, this situation would also be specific to this dll/device. I would probably end up writing different plugins for all browsers I assume...